# Oracle Session State Store Class in ASP.Net C#

Tags: oracle

I am implementing in a development project Oracle Session State Store Class, which is found in Oracle 11g Client to hold my users Sessions as the application is being run over a web farm.

Whilst I can make Oracle Session State Store work through the web.config, I need to make the store work in the code behind because our database connections i.e. the passwords are encrypted and are only decrypted when a connection is made. Unfortunately, I cannot do this in the web.config.

I have tried to implement the Oracle Session State Store Class in the Global.asax in the Session_Start method using the Initialise method. The problem is that it is throwing an error. The exception it is calling is "The connectionStringName attribute is empty or does not exist in the configuration file, or an invalid attribute is found in the configuration file."

In the Session_Start method, I created a Name Value Collection and added two variables, one of which is the database connection string and the other the type for the custom session store.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your `web.config` or `machine.config` is configured correctly. You can take a look at [Oracle Session State Store documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10928_01/OracleSessionStateStoreClass.htm#BABIBEBA), or below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns=
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="my_sessionstate_app_con_string" connectionString=
      "User Id=scott;Password=tiger;Data Source=Oracle"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <!-- Enable and customize OracleSessionStateProvider -->
    <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MyOracleSessionStateStore">
      <providers>
        <add name="MyOracleSessionStateStore" 
             type="Oracle.Web.SessionState.OracleSessionStateStore, 
             Oracle.Web, Version=2.111.6.20, Culture=neutral, 
             PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" 
             connectionStringName="my_sessionstate_app_con_string"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Second, you don't HAVE to encrypt your Oracle session state store connection string during development time. You can use aspnet_regiis to encrypt it at deployment like below.

```
aspnet_regiis -pef connectionStrings "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\"
```

If the command line above runs fine but your web app produces RSA error messages, try to add the following accounts (or the specific ones you use) to the RSA container:

```
aspnet_regiis -pc "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" -exp
aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "ASPNET"
aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "NETWORK SERVICE"
aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
```

By the way, I didn't have to implement `OracleSessionStateStore` in `Global.ascx`. I just reference with `Session["key"] = value;` and `var value = Session["key"];`
Also, make sure your DBA setup a job to clean up the session state table.