# Implement session state with the oracle mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I see many articles out there on how to implement session with sql server, but when it comes to Oracle, is almost nonexistent, and what has is incomplete. To implement simply declare a sessionState in web.config with the connection string and run to hug or have to do anything else? 
How can I test it later in a test environment? 
Have a secret?

I am using asp.net mvc c# 4 ..

I found this but it is not enough:

[Oracle Session State Store Class](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10928_01/OracleSessionStateStoreClass.htm)

[Oracle Session State Store Class in ASP.Net C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304637/oracle-session-state-store-class-in-asp-net-c-sharp)

Comment: Did you find out more about this? It's what i have to start looking into

Comment: You have to implement a class in your model folder and put the [oracle session his link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304637/oracle-session-state-store-class-in-asp-net-c-sharp) code and change as needed and change your web.config to work with your new class session. From then on go debugging and changing needs. It's complicated, but it works.

Comment: I had a problem with it when I was using the lib Oracle.DataAccess.Client. [Here this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043754/custom-sessionstate-oracle-sessionstatestoreproviderbase?noredirect=1#comment39028126_25043754).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is **Oracle Session State Provider**, you need to do some Installation. Here is the guide : [Oracle Providers for ASP.NET Installation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e18737/IntroInstallation.htm#BHCGAGGB)