# Custom SessionState Oracle SessionStateStoreProviderBase

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, visual-studio-2013

I created a ***custom session class*** and inherited the [SessionStateStoreProviderBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatestoreproviderbase(v=vs.110).aspx) connecting the oracle.

I'm using [this how-to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms178589(v=vs.100).aspx), just replace with the connection classes of [Oracle.DataAccess](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html).

Until then everything working locally but when I publish on iis 7.5 server with a custom class SessionStateStoreProviderBase is still working, but the variable "[session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httpsessionstatebase(v=vs.110).aspx)" ([HttpSessionStateBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httpsessionstatebase(v=vs.110).aspx)) are zero (null). Ex: Session["idUser"].
Anything I'm forgetting? Please I need help, because the documentation does not seem to be clear about that.

My web.config:

```
   <sessionState timeout="30" mode="Custom" cookieless="false" customProvider="CustomSessionProvider" sessionIDManagerType="namespace.CustomSessionIdManager">
      <providers>
        <add name="CustomSessionProvider" type="namespace.SessionDataProvider" connectionStringName="connectionOracle" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login" defaultUrl="~/Inicio" />
    </authentication>
```

Error Log IIS:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2014-08-05 01:14:37
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2014-08-05 01:14:37 192.168.xxx.xx GET / - 80 - 10.100.xxx.xx Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/34.0.1847.131+Safari/537.36 302 0 0 6239
2014-08-05 01:14:37 192.168.xxx.xx GET /Inicio - 80 - 10.100.xxx.xx Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/34.0.1847.131+Safari/537.36 500 0 0 374
```

Exception in the controller:

object reference not set to an instance of an object
Verify before if session is null.

Thank you.

Comment: We may need some parts of your code

Comment: My did not post my code because it is large and is equal to this instance, only substituting for oracle odbc connections. 
see:http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms178589(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: **Session_Start** is also not executed. Nothing works with session when put to custom. Only with cookie and in_proc. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I took a look at the example. Nothing suspicious there. Do you need help debugging it? I will also take a look again with the new information.

Comment: I did a local simulation disabling the module session and was reproduced the same error when I publish to the server. Simply login module does not seem to be working and I have no experience in iis. Ai gives error in any statement using session.

Comment: after he writes the idSession and the date and other information successfully it gives error when you try to check session. 
Session ["nameUser"]! = Null 

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I will be at home in about 1 hour. Can you wait till then?

Comment: *Of course*. I really appreciate your help. Any light will be welcome. I can not find anything about it on the net.

Comment: These kinds of problems are rate because people often go with the ready solutions and explorers like you get left alone:)

Comment: Some light at the end of the tunnel? I do not believe this is happening, because I have read many docs and the business has become simple for me, but this error just do not agree. Localhost everything works wonderful, but nothing done on the server. I'm already condemning the iis default and putting it and the worst, I am running iis tfs this.

Comment: I tried to break it in many ways since last year. It seems OK to me. Maybe placing some logs could help. Just to confirm: writing something into Session will work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58503/discussion-between-alireza-and-fernando).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging my best custom class session, I noticed that when trying to convert an integer he took exception, but it worked localhost, but not on the server. Skirted the problem by making another type of conversion, [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx) using the framework rather than the [GetInt32](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleDataReaderClass.htm#i1005172) odt Oracle. *Do not know why so it functioned, but not on the server, and reproduce the same situation*.

With this error he did not arrive in the method 'CreateNewStoreData'.

Works well. Ex: reader.IsDBNull(2) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader[2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleDataReaderClass.htm#i1005172));

Does not work well. Ex: reader.IsDBNull(2) ? 0 : reader.GetInt32(2);

*Thanks for your help and attention.*

Thank '[Alireza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2835365/alireza)'! :)